# Traefik container has no mount on docker inspect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik, windows-container

I have an error that only happens when I run `docker compose up` on one of my docker compose files and not the other, even though the services named "proxy" in which the error occurs are identical.

When I run `docker compose -f docker-compose-v1.yml up -d` the containers start without issue but on inspection the container named github_proxy_1 has **no mounts**.

If I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-v2.yml up -d` the containers start without issue and on inspection the container named github_proxy_1 **has mounts**.

The proxy services are based on traefik windows images. I have read that many have had issues with binding volumes so that traefik can communicate with the underlying host, but the weird thing is that it works flawlessly in one setup but not the other.

Below are my docker version info, docker compose files, the results when inspecting the containers (showing the difference in mounts), and the error message from the container log shown in Docker Desktop.

Why does one proxy container manage to populate mounts while the other doesn't?

Thanks in advance!

**docker version**

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.14
 Version:           20.10.6
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.3
 Git commit:        370c289
 Built:             Fri Apr  9 22:49:36 2021   
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.6
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8728dd2
  Built:            Fri Apr  9 22:45:40 2021   
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

**docker-compose-v1.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  s4-web:
    image: s4admin:484-2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: S4/Admin/Dockerfile
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)"
    networks:
      - sg-net

  proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.3-windowsservercore-1809
    command:
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=sg-net"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8088:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: npipe
        source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
    networks:
      - sg-net

networks:
  sg-net:
```

**docker-compose-v2.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  signup-web:
    image: signup-web:02-06
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: docker/02-06-platform-integration/signup-web/v6/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - Dependencies:IReferenceDataLoader=SignUp.Web.ReferenceData.ApiReferenceDataLoader
      - ReferenceDataApi:Url=http://reference-data-api/api
      - Dependencies:IProspectSaveHandler=SignUp.Web.ProspectSave.AsynchronousProspectSaveHandler
      - MessageQueue:Url=nats://${HOST_IP}:4222
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)"
    networks:
      - signup-net

  proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.3-windowsservercore-1809
    command:
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=signup-net"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8088:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: npipe
        source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
    networks:
      - signup-net

networks:
  signup-net:
```

Result from **docker inspect github_proxy_1** showing no mounts:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "507bb53f9f7c772221ef858464877d310c4ab48a100f86e49b5e248de67c5921",
        "Created": "2021-05-28T07:49:16.3839919Z",
        "Path": "/traefik",
        "Args": [
            "--providers.docker",
            "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine",    
            "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false",
            "--providers.docker.network=sg-net",
            "--entrypoints.web.address=:80",
            "--api.insecure=true"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1312,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-05-28T07:49:22.9474168Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:0011bc7c1cd89741d499d69fe62ed8c50b251d90bb3dd01350d6f945dace6e89",
        "ResolvConfPath": "",
        "HostnamePath": "",
        "HostsPath": "",
        "LogPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\containers\\507bb53f9f7c772221ef858464877d310c4ab48a100f86e49b5e248de67c5921\\507bb53f9f7c772221ef858464877d310c4ab48a100f86e49b5e248de67c5921-json.log",
        "Name": "/github_proxy_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "windowsfilter",
        "Platform": "windows",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "github_sg-net",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ],
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8088"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 0,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "hyperv",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": null,
            "ReadonlyPaths": null
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "dir": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\507bb53f9f7c772221ef858464877d310c4ab48a100f86e49b5e248de67c5921"
            },
            "Name": "windowsfilter"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "507bb53f9f7c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {},
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": [
                "--providers.docker",
                "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine",                "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false",
                "--providers.docker.network=sg-net",
                "--entrypoints.web.address=:80",
                "--api.insecure=true"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:0011bc7c1cd89741d499d69fe62ed8c50b251d90bb3dd01350d6f945dace6e89",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/traefik"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "ef67d49c829762590f72bf6caa8e34327f9b86915e9e985c9d2fa43177457894",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "github",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "C:\\Dev\\Projects\\SurveyGenerator\\github\\docker-compose-s4.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "C:\\Dev\\Projects\\SurveyGenerator\\github",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "proxy",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.0-alpha",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "A modern reverse-proxy",
                "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://docs.traefik.io",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "Traefik",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://traefik.io",        
                "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "Traefik Labs",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "v2.3.7"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "507bb53f9f7c772221ef858464877d310c4ab48a100f86e49b5e248de67c5921",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ],
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8088"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "507bb53f9f7c772221ef858464877d310c4ab48a100f86e49b5e248de67c5921",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "github_sg-net": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "proxy",
                        "github_proxy_1",
                        "507bb53f9f7c"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "2e5931b8cba8fdd1b2b4e547089c21b85570450437599d13e8af3888263d22e3",
                    "EndpointID": "87d39c2b7cc69b3090026f8395312704e684d7fb925410895dca1a007473ee41",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.160.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.27.163.11",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:46:69:3c",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Result from **docker inspect github_proxy_1** where mounts has values:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "a81aae03a323b5efd37f80656dccab0bd102aa903d34803554456f0661c22c99",
        "Created": "2021-05-28T08:21:05.6675713Z",
        "Path": "/traefik",
        "Args": [
            "--providers.docker",
            "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine",
            "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false",
            "--providers.docker.network=signup-net",
            "--entrypoints.web.address=:80",
            "--api.insecure=true"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1328,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-05-28T08:21:10.4771044Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:0011bc7c1cd89741d499d69fe62ed8c50b251d90bb3dd01350d6f945dace6e89",
        "ResolvConfPath": "",
        "HostnamePath": "",
        "HostsPath": "",
        "LogPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\containers\\a81aae03a323b5efd37f80656dccab0bd102aa903d34803554456f0661c22c99\\a81aae03a323b5efd37f80656dccab0bd102aa903d34803554456f0661c22c99-json.log",
        "Name": "/03_proxy_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "windowsfilter",
        "Platform": "windows",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "03_signup-net",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ],
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8088"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 0,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "hyperv",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "npipe",
                    "Source": "\\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine",
                    "Target": "\\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine"
                }
            ],
            "MaskedPaths": null,
            "ReadonlyPaths": null
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "dir": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a81aae03a323b5efd37f80656dccab0bd102aa903d34803554456f0661c22c99"
            },
            "Name": "windowsfilter"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "npipe",
                "Source": "\\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine",
                "Destination": "\\\\.\\pipe\\docker_engine",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "a81aae03a323",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {},
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": [
                "--providers.docker",
                "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine",
                "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false",
                "--providers.docker.network=signup-net",
                "--entrypoints.web.address=:80",
                "--api.insecure=true"
            ],
            "Image": "traefik:v2.3-windowsservercore-1809",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/traefik"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "53f350716aad96821fea12154c09bf70e538394230171e0139d28b0ea8b6a2c6",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "03",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "app\\03\\v7-windows.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "C:\\Dev\\Projects\\docker4dotnet\\app\\03",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "proxy",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.1",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "A modern reverse-proxy",
                "org.opencontainers.image.documentation": "https://docs.traefik.io",
                "org.opencontainers.image.title": "Traefik",
                "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://traefik.io", 
                "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "Traefik Labs",    
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "v2.3.7"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "a81aae03a323b5efd37f80656dccab0bd102aa903d34803554456f0661c22c99",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ],
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8088"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "a81aae03a323b5efd37f80656dccab0bd102aa903d34803554456f0661c22c99",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "03_signup-net": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "a81aae03a323",
                        "proxy"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "1a464d92f0625acd600391c7b2204d33e54cb94b1bf4a098ca0a48e5f4067edc",
                    "EndpointID": "fde1dace014a898a4cee3fb624ce1a1ec74f87a565b3cb4696e895037774e57d",
                    "Gateway": "172.29.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.29.12.143",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:2f:e3:79",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Logged error message in docker desktop for the github_proxy_1 container without mounts:

```
time="2021-05-28T09:49:25+02:00" level=error msg="Failed to retrieve information of the docker client and server host: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get \"http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version\": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified." providerName=docker

time="2021-05-28T09:49:25+02:00" level=error msg="Provider connection error error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get \"http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version\": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified., retrying in 552.330144ms" providerName=docker
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. I was using `docker-compose` (using the docker-compose binary) for the compose that worked and `docker compose` for the one that didn't.

The question remains why one works and the other doesn't, what is the difference of running `docker-compose` vs `docker compose`? Does it perhaps somehow have to do with permissions?